# C# parse XML from HTML Body and save to file

Tags: c#, html, xml

C# after performing GET from the API it returns the XML code embedded in the HTML file similar to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <title>config</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
<CONFIG="2"/>
<VALUE1="1"/>
<VALUE2="2"/>
<CONFIGEND="0"/>

    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to save the XML content from the body "<CONFIG ... CONFIGEND="0"/>" out to a file.  My attempts using HtmlAgilityPack result in the XML data being modified as follows:

```
<CONFIG="2"></CONFIG>
...
<CONFIGEND="0"></CONFIGEND>
```

I am new to C# (and programming in general) so please be kind.  Search attempts have left me more confused than I started :/

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO!
What is the API you using and why it is needed to put XML into HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have figured out *HtmlAgilityPack* is converting something.
Html actually an Xml file. But *System.Xml.XmlDocument* cannot handle this html file. So you need to parse manually.

As Anis R. says, best way is RegularExpressions. To use RegularExpressions, you need to add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` to first lines.

Let's say your Html content is in *htmlstring* variable.

Firstly you need to define pattern for your case.

```
string regexPattern = @"\<body\>(.*?)\<\/body\>";
Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

You need to use *RegexOptions.Singleline* option. Because your html content will have new line characters.

```
string body = regex.Match(htmlstring).Value;
```

With this, you will have :

```
<body>
        
<CONFIG="2"/>
<VALUE1="1"/>
<VALUE2="2"/>
<CONFIGEND="0"/>

    </body>
```

To remove body tags ;

```
string result = body.Replace("<body>", "").Replace("</body>", "");
```

To trim leading and trailing spaces;

```
string prettierResult = result.Trim();
```

Now you have ;

```
<CONFIG="2"/>
<VALUE1="1"/>
<VALUE2="2"/>
<CONFIGEND="0"/>
```

To save content to a file ;

```
File.WriteAllText("c:\\path-to-save", prettierResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

**If the format is consistent<sup>1</sup>** (e.g., you always want everything between `<body>...</body>`), then one way is to use a regex:

```cs
string pattern = @"<body>(.*)</body>";  
Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);  
        
string html = "<body>Content here</body>";  
        
// get first match and print it
Match firstMatch = rg.Matches(html)[0];
Console.WriteLine(firstMatch.Groups[1]); // "Content here"
```

(PS: this will need `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`)

---

<sup>1</sup> Keeping [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7692859) in mind

Comment: Thank you for this @Anis R., it got me on the correct track.  I had to modify yours slightly, referencing https://www.brightfunction.co.uk/remove-html-with-regular-expressions/ as well.

Comment: "If the format is consistent" - *if* is being the operating word here. Regular expression [should not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6751339/4317297) be used to parse HTML. While it may work in this particular case, in general, it is a bad idea.

Comment: @Riwen Absolutely! I guess I should have better emphasized it - Answer edited. However, when you only want to handle a very specific case (like here), it can be okay.

Comment: @Riwen I tried several other methods and always ended up with modified XML data.  I understand RegEx should not be used in general - this is a very specific case where the formatting won't ever deviate.  If you have a solution I welcome it!